# Hide UIView and adjust the other widgets to take space?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a screen where there are three components, `Header`, `CollectionView` and `bottomView`. I want to show the bottom view only on some conditions. I tried setting the `isHidden` property for that bottom view, and it is hiding the view but the space is not taken by the `collectionView`. I want to adjust the `collectionView` to take the remaining space if the bottom view is hidden. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you using the constraints?

Comment: `UIStackView` might be an alternative - any elements in a stack view that are hidden automatically shrink to zero width/height.

Comment: I suggest to use UIStackView in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the height constraint of the bottom view and toggle hide/show with this

```
self.bottomHeight.constant = show ? 100 : 0
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Did the same thing but its not working
self.bottomView.isHidden = false
self.bottomViewHeight.constant = 100
self.calculateOrderTotal()
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Answer (score 0):

The isHidden property change only the visibility of the view, not also the constraints.

You can connect the collectionview bottom constraint to the top of the bottom view and then the bottom view bottom contraint to the bottom of the parent view.

Then get an IBOutlet of the height constraint of the bottomView and change his constant like in this code:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottomContraint;

...

bottomContraint.constant = 0 // To hide
yourView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height constraint of the bottom view to 0. This way, it will hide the bottom view as well as the collection will resize according to the constraints.

Note that you should have given constraints like:
Header: leading-top-trailing space to superview (or safeAreaLayoutGuide) and fixed height.
Collection: leading-trailing to superview, top space to header.

Footer: Leading-trailing-bottom to superview (or better: safeAreaLayoutGuide), top space to collection, And **Fixed Height**.

You need to update constant of the **FixedHeight** constraint of footerview.